# Can we ignore the format of the content in ansible and write it to a file?

Tags: ansible

The file content I want to store in a file would be something like:

```
groups:
- name: textfile_collector_alert.rules
  rules:
  - alert: service_oom
    expr: service_oom_file == 1
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      description: 'Hprof files: {{ $labels.file }}. Reported by instance {{ $labels.instance
        }} of job {{ $labels.job }}.'
      summary: OOM happens
```

I've tried different forms in the following two aspects:

- `printf` in [*shell module*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/shell_module.html) and
- `content copy` in [*copy module*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/copy_module.html)

but neither worked.

Encountering the same error:

```
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: template error while templating string: unexpected char u'$' at 213
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have no proper solutions to handle the ***format issue*** mentioned in the question in Ansible (have no no experience with Ansible).

Having a solution as:

#### Write to local file using Java

```
public static boolean writeToLocal(String absFilePath, String content) {
    File file = new File(absFilePath);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try {
        Files.write(file.toPath(), Arrays.asList(content));
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### Copy local file to remote using Ansible

```
- name: Copy local file to remote
  copy:
    src: "{{ tmpLocalRuleFile }}"
    dest: "{{ tmpFolder }}/{{ tmpRuleFile }}"
  become: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you want is `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` to switch off Jinja2 template evaluation:

```
- debug:
    msg: >-
     {% raw %}this is some golang {{ $and can have whatever }}{% endraw %}
```

I believe it's possible to also switch the jinja2 escape characters away from the mustaches, but I haven't ever personally tried it to know how easy that is (or, of course, whether it really works).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just tried it using `shell: printf {% raw %} '{{ ruleContent }}' {% endraw %} > "{{ tmpFolder }}/{{ tmpRuleFile }}";`, but the content now is just `ruleContent` while the value of this variable is not retrieved as expected.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following what problem you're trying to solve; in your examples, you have golang template text, that for sure should not be interpreted by jinja2 (thus leading to your "unexpected char u'$' at 213" message). But now you're trying to printf something -- an **absolutely terrible idea** -- and expecting `ruleContent` to be evaluated, even though you explicitly put it inside `{% raw %}`?

Comment: Sorry for the bad try, I was just trying to write the file content to a temp file and that’s all. I have no idea what jinja2 is (though read some posts about it).